# Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred Error in my Kotlin Multiplatform project

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, swiftui, kotlin-multiplatform

Why am I getting the following error on build?

```
Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred in Kotlin Multiplatform project
```

```swift
import SwiftUI
import shared

struct ManagementResourceState<T : AnyObject, SuccessView : View>: View {
    private let resourceState: BasicUiState
    private let successView: (T?) -> SuccessView
    private let onTryAgain: () -> Void
    private let msgTryAgain: String
    private let onCheckAgain: () -> Void
    private let msgCheckAgain: String

    init(
        resourceState: BasicUiState,
        successView:  @escaping (T?) -> SuccessView,
        onTryAgain: @escaping () -> Void,
        msgTryAgain: String = "An error has ocurred",
        onCheckAgain: @escaping () -> Void,
        msgCheckAgain: String = "No data to show"
    ) {
        self.resourceState = resourceState
        self.successView = successView
        self.onTryAgain = onTryAgain
        self.msgTryAgain = msgTryAgain
        self.onCheckAgain = onCheckAgain
        self.msgCheckAgain = msgCheckAgain
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        switch self.resourceState { // Error on this line
            case is BasicUiStateEmpty:
                EmptyView(msg: self.msgCheckAgain, onClick: self.onCheckAgain)
            case is BasicUiStateError:
                ErrorView(msg: self.msgTryAgain, onClick: self.onTryAgain)
            case is BasicUiStateLoading:
                LoadingView()
            case let success as BasicUiStateSuccess<T>:
                successView(success.data)
            default:
                Text("You shouldn't be seeing this message")
        }
    }
}
```

`BasicUiState` in Kotlin project looks like:

```kotlin
sealed interface BasicUiState<out T> {
    data class Success <T>(val data:T):BasicUiState<T>
    data class Error <T>(val msg:String? = null):BasicUiState<T>
    object Loading:BasicUiState<Nothing>
    object Empty:BasicUiState<Nothing>
    object Idle:BasicUiState<Nothing>
}
```

[image]

P.S. Thank you for your replies. I apologize if the question is stupid. I'm more of an Android developer than IOS. Just trying to figure out a Kotlin Multiplatform project.

Comment: Don't know if this is your issue since I don't use multiplatform, but I think your error class should be defined without a generic type: `data class Error(val msg: String? = null): BasicUiState<Nothing>`

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you very much, your answer helped me. The problem was indeed that the Error class was parametrized by the generic.